# What does Hibernate's load() method do for non-existing IDs?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm a bit confused by the JavaDocs on [Session.load](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29):

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, assuming
>   that the instance exists. This method might return a proxied instance that is initialized on-demand,
>   when a non-identifier method is accessed.
>
> You should not use this method to determine if an instance exists (use get() instead). Use this
>   only to retrieve an instance that you assume exists, where non-existence would be an actual error.

I understand I'm supposed to use get, but what I don't understand is what is meant with the bit about it initialized on demand when a non-identifier method is used.

For me, if I have a class and use `load(MyClass.class, NonExistingID)`, and then print the output of the `getId()` on the returned instance, it seems to automatically produce a new instance with `NonExistingID` every single time. Why is this?

I'm just trying to understand, is `getId()` a non-identifying method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Non-identifier method' means a method that returns something besides the identifier (as in primary key id) for the object. `load` gives you a proxy, where the proxy only queries the database once you ask it for something besides the identifier. So `getId` is an identifier method, Hibernate doesn't query the database for its value (it doesn't have to because you passed it into the `load` method call).

Found this snippet on [the hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2387456):

> An important scenario under which you need to contrast the load and
>   get methods of the Hibernate Session has to do with what happens when
>   you provide a primary key that doesn't actually exist in the database.
>   Well, with the get method, you are simply returned a null object,
>   which is no big deal.
>
> With the load method, there's also no initial problem when you provide
>   an invalid primary key to the method. From what you can tell,
>   Hibernate appears to hand you back a valid, non-null instance of the
>   class in which you are interested. However, the problems start when
>   you actually try to access a property of that instance - that's where
>   you run into trouble.
>
> Remember how I said the load method doesn't hit the database until a
>   property of the bean is requested? Well, if you've provided a primary
>   key that doesn't exist in your database to the load method, when it
>   does go to the database for the first time, it won't be able to find
>   the non-existent, associated record, and your code will cough up big
>   time. In fact, looking up a field based upon a non-existent primary
>   key with the Hibernate Session's load method triggers the following
>   error:
>
> org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given
>   identifier exists: [User#123]

So it sounds like you have used load to get a proxy for a nonexistent object, but since you haven't called any 'nonidentifier methods' on it, you haven't forced the proxy to hit the database and haven't gotten an error.

Answer (score 8):

Just to make long story short:

**session.load** will create proxy object which will be initialized when you call any getter of non-primary key class item.

**session.get** will return null if the object does not exist and will return the full object if it does exist.