# hibernate object loading failing

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Java and Hibernate in my project. I am facing a very peculiar problem. Whenever i load an entity, select in not fired on the database, instead whenever i perform some operation on object like get some value, at that time it fires the select which is called lazy loading. But the problem is i have not stated `lazy="true"` in my HBM file. Also sometimes, load is successful, and then when i try to do some manipulation on the object it gives an error, `ProxyInitializationError Session is Closed`.

Can check the below link for code base :-
http://pastebin.com/yD9ZM3yH

But if in the actual method i put `System.out.println(information.getStudentName());` then the code works properly as the select is fired before the session was closed.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behiavior.

when you are using `session.load(Object.class, id)`the returned object is proxy class. 
Just look at my answer here:

[What does Hibernate's load() method do for non-existing IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422645/what-does-hibernates-load-method-do-for-non-existing-ids/7423007#7423007)

2) you are receiving this error, because as soon as you received your proxy, Hibernate session is closed and proxy initiation throws this exception.

You can read more about it and possible solutions in this technical article.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1: In addition, note that lazy is on by default in Hibernate 3. You don't have to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between session.load and session.get

See this https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2387456 for more details.

The other thing to be mindful of is your transaction boundaries. That is why adding the

```
System.out.println(information.getStudentName());
```

worked. It occurred before the session was closed so the proxy was able to initialise the field.

LAZY versus EAGER load effects when and how related entities (Collections or OneToOne) are loaded, not how the simple properties on the entity is loaded.